# Setting up the options for a series of dynamic selects

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

I have an angular model receives data from an API that looks like:

```
$scope.questions = [
        {name: 'Question 1', options:['Option 1', 'Option 2', 'Option 3'],id: 1},
        {name: 'Question 2', options:['Option A', 'Option B', 'Option C'],id: 2},
        {name: 'Question 3', options:['Option a', 'Option b', 'Option c'],id: 3}

    ]
```

And, I would like to iterate over all the questions and have a series of one select box per question with the select's options coming from the question object

```
<div ng-repeat="question in questions">

<label>{{question.name}}</label><select ng-options="?"></select>

</div>
```

I am having trouble figuring out what the ? should be.  I thought `ng-options="o in question.options"` might work, but no such luck.  Can this be done?  If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [the documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3aselect), it should be

```
o for o in question.options
```

Note that you'll need to specify an ng-model attribute for this to work:

```
<select ng-model="question.selectedOption" ng-options="o for o in question.options"></select>
```

Here's [a plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/4ViLmz5bmIDAbRn1mUof?p=preview) showing that it works.